# jQuery find all elements start with specific id but not with another specific id

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following html:

```
input id="abc_0_1"
input id="rub_0_1"
input id="rub_0_2"
input id="rub_1_1"
input id="rub_1_2"
input id="rub_2_1"
input id="rub_2_1"
input id="abc_4_5"
```

Using jQuery I want to select only the inputs that start with 'rub_' but do not start with 'rub_0'

How can I do it, assuming I have much more inputs with similar ids?

Thanks,

Avi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
var $els = $('input[id^="rub_"]:not([id^="rub_0"])')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('[id^="rub_"]:not('[id^="rub_0"]')
```

Or, like this:

```
$('[id^="rub_"]).filter(function(){
   return $(this).not('[id^="rub_0"]);
})
```

[more details on attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$('input[id^="rub_"]:not([id^="rub_0"]')
```